# Testing variable against multiple values?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I remember seeing a question on here about the same problem, where things like:

```
if( x==null || x==" " || x==" " || x=="\n")...
```

End up becoming long and ugly strings, but the answer wasn't great and I can't remember what it was.

I'm in the middle of a tutorial on MySQL, and the way the problem is solved in SQL is by using the keyword "IN".

```
WHERE value IN (1 , 22, 35)...
```

So I was wondering if it's considered inefficient or bad practice to do:

```
object[] BadVals = {null, " ", "  ", "\n"};
if(Array.IndexOf(BadVals, x) != -1)...
```

Comment: That works, but I would use LINQ instead.

Comment: @linuxuser27, I've always wondered: I know LINQ makes everything a ton easier to type, but is it also more efficient?

Comment: The "switch" statement is very efficient and readable.

Comment: @rontornambe FSVO readable. I personally dislike the syntax :)

Comment: @Walkerneo If we take raw efficiency into it, I don't see much benefit.  However I will always sacrifice a little speed for clean and readable code, where your intent is clear.  The question you need to ask yourself is, "Does a few extra cycles where this code is executing diminish my applications performance?", yes or no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly not efficient in theory as the straight `if` test, but this is a red herring. The real question is: **do you care?**

There's two sides to this question.

1. So what if it's slower? If you aren't running this on a CPU-bound loop that executes a million times, the difference is purely theoretical. Use whatever makes for more bug-free code that's a pleasure to read and maintain.
2. So what if it's uglier? Are you going to be writing this lots of times? Surely not -- if you intend to *use* it lots of times, put it inside a well-named method and never think about it again.

As for the LINQ approach, that's slightly shorter and a bit more readable than what you have:

```
if((new[] { null, " ", "  ", "\n" }).Contains(x)) ...
```

You 'd probably want to write another extension method that allows you to call this with the operand positions reversed, e.g.

```
if(x.In(new[] { null, " ", "  ", "\n" })) ...
```

**Verdict:** I 'd go with LINQ for more than 3 or so values to test against, provided that there's no other more obvious way to check for these values (e.g. in this case [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) is awfully close) and there are no obvious performance implications. Otherwise, `if` is tried and true.

Comment: The LINQ is much cleaner code. If you have tons of values to check against, then use a List of something more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily bad practice, but there are some other ways.  A couple of different ways are:

1. For null/empty Strings,

   ```
   String.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Trim());
   ```
2. [`IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) in 4.0:

   ```
    String.IsNullOrWhitespace(s.Trim());
   ```
3. for an operator like SQL `IN`:

   ```
   if((new[] {" ", "  ", "\n"}).Contains(s))
   {
   }
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately this will explode when `s` is null. A slight variant I use: `if ((s ?? "").Trim() == "") { /* "empty" */ }`

Answer (score 1):

These matters of style are seldom absolute, and largely dependent on the specific problem that is being solved, as well as organizational considerations and personal preferences.  This said, one well-regarded reference (Code Complete by Steve McDonnell) advises to [simplify complicated tests with boolean function calls](http://books.google.com/books?id=3JfE7TGUwvgC&pg=PT567&lpg=PT567&dq=%22simplify+complicated+tests+with+boolean+function+calls%22&source=bl&ots=RQsZ6K5H9M&sig=wKdKM5FrZ_-z9zsEvthGhBy0zFE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kcgUT5jyHKPx0gHwsNSjAw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22simplify%20complicated%20tests%20with%20boolean%20function%20calls%22&f=false) as a means to reduce the complexity in if statements.  For instance, one might replace the if statement above with something like:

```
if (IsStringFoo(s)) {...}
```

Elsewhere defined as

```
// Returns true if and only if the input string is a Foo
bool IsStringFoo(string s)
{
    return s == "" || s == " " || s == "\n";
    // or use the alternate array syntax here instead if you prefer
}
```

This communicates to the consumer not just the logical mechanics, but also potentially the business rationale for these mechanics, thus likely improving readability.

Using the `in` syntax proposed could suffer from similar readability issues -- in particular, it's still unclear as to *why* those particular tests are being done.  The latter method may be potentially more difficult to understand since the "or" communicates a boolean logic operation in a way Array.IndexOf does not necessarily.